# Binding DataTemplateSelector with treeview item programmatically in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am not able to bind the data template selector with tree view item programmatically.
Here i have created the parameterized data template selector , this can not be bound with tree view in XAML.
Here is code for data template selector

```
 public class MyTemplate : DataTemplateSelector
    {

        private IVM_ManyToOneMapping _viewModel;
        public MyTemplate(IVM_ManyToOneMapping viewModel)
        {
            _viewModel = viewModel;
        }
    }
```

tried approach :
MyTemplate  obj= new MyTemplate(viewModel)
treeviewList.ItemTemplateSelector = obj;

it is not working.

Comment: please can you show some more code

Answer (score 0):

This is not how a `DataTemplateSelector` works:

Here an **example**:

```
public class TemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{

    //You override this function to select your data template based in the given item
    public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, 
                    System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
    {
        if(item is MyViewModel1)
            return DataTemplate1;
        if(item is MyViewModel2)
            return DataTemplate2;
        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

But if you are already in code behind, why would you need a `DataTemplateSelector`?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22011896/4558029) is a nice example, how to get things bindable and more dynamic

Comment: Thanks for response . I wanted to bind the data template selector of tree view from code (Not through XAML). I am able to achieve it thanks..:)

Answer (score 0):

HierarchicalDataTemplate hierarchicalTemplate = new HierarchicalDataTemplate();

```
        // create TreeViewItem.
        FrameworkElementFactory treeViewItem = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TreeViewItem));
        treeViewItem.SetBinding(TreeViewItem.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding("GroupList"));
        treeViewItem.SetValue(TreeViewItem.ItemTemplateSelectorProperty,
                               new TreeViewItemTemplateSelector(_viewModel));

        hierarchicalTemplate.VisualTree = treeViewItem;
```

treeviewList.itemTemplate=hierarchicalTemplate;