# Binding not working anymore when using TemplateSelector in DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, datatemplateselector

I have the following (working) `XAML` definition:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Station &amp; Programm" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                                                
            <ListBox 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Targets}" 
                Style="{StaticResource ListBoxTransparentStyle}"    
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"> <!--Disable Selection-->
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Text="{Binding Station}"
                                Height="Auto"/>
                            <TextBlock
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Text="{Binding Program}"
                                Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I want to outsource this `DataTemplate` and use the following `DataTemplateSelector`:

```
public class ZlsRouteEditorDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ViewDataTemplate { get;set; }
    public DataTemplate EditDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is ERouteEditor e)
        {
            switch (e)
            {
                case ERouteEditor.View:
                    return ViewDataTemplate;
                case ERouteEditor.Edit:
                    return EditDataTemplate;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
        }
        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

Afterwards I have changed my code as follow:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="StationProgramView" x:Shared="True">                                                
            <ListBox 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Targets}" 
                Style="{StaticResource ListBoxTransparentStyle}"    
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"> <!--Disable Selection-->
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <controls:HtTextfeld
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Text="{Binding Station}"
                                DisableTranslation="True"
                                Height="Auto"/>
                            <controls:HtTextfeld
                                Grid.Column="2"
                                Text="{Binding Program}"
                                DisableTranslation="True"
                                Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="StationProgramEdit" x:Shared="True">                                                
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <recipeControls:ZlsRouteEditorDataTemplateSelector x:Key="StationProgramTemplateSelector" ViewDataTemplate="{StaticResource StationProgramView}" EditDataTemplate="{StaticResource StationProgramEdit}"/>
```

---

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Station &amp; Programm" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentControl
                ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource StationProgramTemplateSelector}"
                Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=recipeControls:ZlsRouteEditor}, Path=Mode}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The `DataTemplate`s are selected correctly, but the data binding does not work anymore.

Comment: Why are you setting the x:Shared attribute of the DataTemplate to true?

Comment: I thought, If you use a `DataTemplate` for more than one (for every row in the `DataGrid`) instance, set this flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my personal solution how to get it working.

I have changed the `ZlsRouteEditorDataTemplateSelector` class with the ability to look for my specific control (`ZlsRouteEditor`) and get the `Mode` value.

#### ZlsRouteEditorDataTemplateSelector

```
public class ZlsRouteEditorDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ViewDataTemplate { get;set; }
    public DataTemplate EditDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is ERouteEditor e)
            return _GetTemplate(e);

        ZlsRouteEditor parent = container.TryFindParent<ZlsRouteEditor>();
        if (parent != null)
            return _GetTemplate(parent.Mode);

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }

    private DataTemplate _GetTemplate(ERouteEditor e)
    {
        switch (e)
        {
            case ERouteEditor.View:
                return ViewDataTemplate;
            case ERouteEditor.Edit:
                return EditDataTemplate;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}
```

#### TryFindParent

```
/// <summary>
/// Finds a parent of a given item on the visual tree.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the queried item.</typeparam>
/// <param name="child">A direct or indirect child of the
/// queried item.</param>
/// <returns>The first parent item that matches the submitted
/// type parameter. If not matching item can be found, a null
/// reference is being returned.</returns>
public static T TryFindParent<T>(this DependencyObject child) where T : DependencyObject
{
    //get parent item
    DependencyObject parentObject = GetParentObject(child);

    //we've reached the end of the tree
    if (parentObject == null) return null;

    //check if the parent matches the type we're looking for
    T parent = parentObject as T;
    if (parent != null)
    {
        return parent;
    }
    else
    {
        //use recursion to proceed with next level
        return TryFindParent<T>(parentObject);
    }
}
```

Then call it directly (like **mm8** said)

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Station &amp; Programm" Width="*" CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource StationProgramTemplateSelector}"/>
```

---

> Where, why and when do you need to Mode property?

I have bound a `recipe` object to the `ZlsRouteEditor` control to **view** or **edit** the `recipe`.

To avoid multiple controls or `Styles` (`ZlsRouteEditorView`, `ZlsRouteEditorEdit` ... ), I made an `enum` `ERouteEditor` as `DependencyProperty` in the `ZlsRouteEditor` to change the `DataTemplates` of specific areas inside of my `Template`.

[image]

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <recipeControls:ZlsRouteEditor Height="570" Margin="5" Mode="View"/>
    <recipeControls:ZlsRouteEditor Height="570" Margin="5" Mode="Edit"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the  `CellTemplateSelector` property of the column rather than setting the `CellTemplate` to a `ContentControl`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Station &amp; Programm" Width="*" CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource StationProgramTemplateSelector}" />
```

The `DataContext` of the root element in the `ContentTemplate` of a `ContentControl` is the `Content` of the same `ContentControl`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried this solution, but how to pass my `Mode` property (`Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=recipeControls:ZlsRouteEditor}, Path=Mode}"/>`) into the `StationProgramTemplateSelector`? Depending on it's value, the `DataTemplate` is chosen. - Answered by myself -> Set another `property` in the class for it! Thanks anyway!

Comment: **Set another property in the class for it!** is not possible, because you can't bind the property. Binding is only possible on `DependencyObject`s and `DataTemplateSelector` isn't. If I use the workaround to use `ContentControl` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011005/bind-a-property-to-datatemplateselector), I will stuck at the same problem than the question I asked!