# Why do some controls need Dependency properties for binding while others do not? How to bind RichTextBox.Document?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, richtextbox

I had 1 custom control that needed to bind data to 2 differents UserControls:

```xml
        <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Title}">
        </TextBlock>

        <RichTextBox
                x:Name="RichTextBoxControl"
                Focusable="False"
                Document="{Binding UserLogs}">
        </RichTextBox>
```

The properties they are trying to bind to are in the same DataContext and are defined as such:

```
public string Title {
    get => return _title;
    set {
        _title = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
private string _title;

public FlowDocument UserLogs {
    get => return _userlogs;
    set {
        _userlogs = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
private FlowDocument _userlogs;
```

I get 0 trouble for the binding of the TextBlock (neither at compile time, nor at runtime).
Though for the binding of the RichTextBox, i get an error with the analyzer of Visual Studio (and at runtime in `InitializeComponent()` of my UserControl): "`Impossible to define 'Binding' on the 'Document' property of type 'RichTextBox'. A binding can only be defined on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject`"

So I am very aware of how to fix that error with the DependencyProperty tricks, but I really don't understand what's the difference between those 2 bindings and why would I have to use a DependencyProperty for the second binding while the first one works like a charm without it.

I kinda feel like fixing this without understanding the reason behind would be a step forward to ununderstandable black wizardry for me T.T

Any explanation welcome :)

Comment: `A binding can only be defined on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject` because `Document` isn't a `DependencyProperty` that's why... `Text` is a dep obj. for the `TextBox` and hence why it works.

Comment: Ow, so it might depends on the property you bind on too... didn't know that :/ I though I could bind any property that I could modify in code behind without any trouble

Comment: no you only can bind to a `DependencyProperty` ...

Comment: To add some precision, you can only **bind** a dependency property, but you can **bind to** any property. The former is the target of a Binding, the latter is the source.

Comment: Yup, I guessed that as I already fixed the same trouble by creating a DependencyProperty once or so... But I wanted to understand the real reason :)

Comment: Also you may add the `FlowDocument` inside your `RichTextBox` you then can bind to the `Run.Text`. For example `<FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="{Binding something}"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>`

Comment: Yass, I've seen this too ^=^ But the content of my RichTextBox is gonna be really dynamic (gonna use this as a kind of Console for logging) with lots of format editing such as color and fontWeight, so I really needed to bind a complete FlowDocument

Comment: The requirement that the _target_ of a binding must be a dependency property is a well-documented aspect of WPF. See marked duplicates for explanation, discussion, etc. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22011005/bind-a-property-to-datatemplateselector) includes a common work-around using attached properties, which you may be able to use in your scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target of a binding *must*  be a `DependencyProperty`. Since you set the binding on a property of a `RichTextBox` this control is the binding target while the property specified by the `Binding.Path` is the data source. The source can be a common CLI property or any .NET object and XML data.

[image]
[Read Microsoft Docs: Basic data binding concepts (image source)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview#basic-data-binding-concepts)

The basic idea of a `FlowDocument` is that it is editable and supports rich text formatting. Since the document is editable, the instance of `FlowDocument` is not expected to change. Rather will the instance itself, i.e. the document content be modified by the user (or application). Therefore the designers chose to make it a CLI property to promote the direct editing of the document's content, as loading new `FlowDocument` instances can seriously impact performance (my educated guess).

If you still need to bind to a document source you need to implement an attached behavior:

**RichTextBox.cs**

```
public class RichTextBox : DependencyObject
{
  #region DocumentSource attached property

  public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "DocumentSource", 
    typeof(FlowDocument), 
    typeof(RichTextBox), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default(FlowDocument), RichTextBox.OnDocumentSourceChanged));

  public static void SetDocumentSource(DependencyObject attachingElement, FlowDocument value) => attachingElement.SetValue(RichTextBox.DocumentSourceProperty, value);

  public static FlowDocument GetDocumentSource(DependencyObject attachingElement) => (FlowDocument) attachingElement.GetValue(RichTextBox.DocumentSourceProperty);

  #endregion

  private static void OnDocumentSourceChanged(DependencyObject attachingElement, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (!(attachingElement is System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox richTextBox))
    {
      return;
    }

    richTextBox.Document = e.NewValue as FlowDocument;
  }
}
```

### Usage

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <RichTextBox RichTextBox.DocumentSource="{Binding UserLogs}" />
</Window>
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private FlowDocument userlogs;
  public FlowDocument UserLogs 
  {
    get => return this.userlogs;
    set 
    {
      this.userlogs = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```